# adding a column of numpy arrays to an existing Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame to which I would like to add a new column that I will then populate with numpy arrays, such that each row in that column contains a numpy array. I'm using the following approach, and am wondering whether this is the correct approach.

```
df['embeddings'] = pd.Series(dtype='object')
```

Then I would iterate over rows and add computed arrays like so (using `np.zeros(1024)` for illustration only, in reality these are the output of a neural network):

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   df['embeddings'].loc[i] = np.zeros(1024)
```

I tested whether it helps to pre-allocate the cells like so, but didn't notice a difference in execution time when I then iterate over rows, at least not with a DataFrame that only has 200 rows:

```
df['embeddings'] = [np.zeros(1024)] * df.shape[0]
```

As alternative to adding a column to then update the rows in it, one could create the list of numpy arrays first, to then add the list as a new column, but that would require more memory.

Comment: Where are the numpy arrays for the new column coming from? Is there any dependency on other rows in the DataFrame?

Comment: very odd to want to loop... a straight assignment will be far more efficient